# Replace img with nothing when it doesn't exist using ReactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs, image

I would like to replace a non-existing image with nothing in my react component. Is there a way I could use the `onError` to somehow put nothing in the place of the image?

```
render() {
  return (
    <img src={myImage} onError={(e)=>{/*Do something to replace the image with nothing*/}}/>
  )
}
```

Alternatively, I could use jquery to detect the image and if it's not found, I simply `return null` on my `render` function. But as it stands I can't make that work either. This is what my function currently looks like:

```
  checkIfImageExists () {
    return $.get(myImage)
      .done(() => console.warn('found it!', myImage))
      .fail(() => console.warn('didnt fin it!', myImage))
  }

render() {
      console.warn(this.checkIfImageExists())
    if (!this.checkIfImageExists().status) {
      return null
    }
  return (
    <img src={myImage}/>
  )
}
```

Problem with these is that it is never found. Is there anything wrong with my code? How can I fix it so that nothing is rendered when the image is not found?

Comment: use `onError` to change a state variable and use that variable to conditionally render the `<img/>` element

Comment: `onerror="this.remove()"`, better still use an unobtrusive event handler, but the removal logic is the same

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky I'm using a stateless component that ideally should be kept that way. If need that, it would be better to just pass it in a condition and `return null` from the render function. Which I currently can't get working.

Comment: @theJuls The component is stateful class in your case. If it were stateless (plain function), this would require to bring state to parent stateful component and handle it there through props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both cases need to use component `state` to handle image asynchronously:

```
state = { imgSrc: myImage } // depends on where myImage comes from

onImageError = () => {
  this.setState({ imgSrc: null })
}

render() {
  return (
    {this.state.imgSrc && <img src={this.state.imgSrc} onError={this.onImageError }/>}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can hide image using CSS `display: none` and show it `onload`:

```js
class NonEmptyImage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: false
  }
  
  handleLoad = _ => this.setState({ visible: true });
  
  render() {
    const { src } = this.props;
    const { visible } = this.state;
    return (
      <img
        src={src}
        onLoad={this.handleLoad}
        style={{ display: visible ? 'initial' : 'none' }}
      />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NonEmptyImage src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4d/SpongeBob_SquarePants_characters_cast.png/300px-SpongeBob_SquarePants_characters_cast.png'/>, document.querySelector("#fw33f4w5"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="fw33f4w5"></div>
```

Change `src` to something random and you'll see nothing.

If you hate classes here's working example with a function:

```js
function NonEmptyImage({ src }) {
  let ref;

  return (
    <img
      ref={el => ref = el}
      src={src}
      onLoad={_ => ref.style.display = 'initial'}
      style={{ display: 'none' }}
    />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<NonEmptyImage src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4d/SpongeBob_SquarePants_characters_cast.png/300px-SpongeBob_SquarePants_characters_cast.png' />, document.querySelector("#fw33f4w5ert"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="fw33f4w5ert"></div>
```